# Access restriction modules block nodes, but not teasers?

Tags: users

Please forgive if this is bad form - this is my first post here, and I realise it's very similar to [this existing question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/node-access-control-modules-for-members-only-pages), although slightly different.

I'd like my site to have a bunch of public info, some members-only info, and some info only for super-users. All of the content-access modules I've tried seem to work when viewing the actual node, but in the taxonomy pages the teasers for these pages are still visible (thus leaking information). In short, you can see which pages you're not allowed to read in full, and that's a problem.

How can I make sure that users only see content --in any way-- that they are permitted to see?

I've implemented my access model by making three distinct roles (well, anonymous, authenticated, and "super user"), and three distinct content types for each user role and then assigning access based on content type, although for a very few nodes I do need to override this with node-level access control (for making a super-user page available in view-only mode to regular members). I'm not interested in per-user access control as such, per-role (with per-node override) is sufficient.

My site runs Drupal v7.2 (but I'm upgrading to 7.4 as I post this), and I've tried the modules named [Node Privacy By Role](http://drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole) and [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access). Both of these work very nicely, except for the issue mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, okay this is a little embarrassing ... I had my Drupal site update itself and its modules, and lo: it suddenly worked as intended. Whee.